# Power Platform admin center - missing "Data export (preview)" option

Tags: azure-application-insights, powerapps, dynamics-365

I've tried to enable synchronization of logs between my Dataverse environment and Azure Application Insights service. I've tried to setup the thing according to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/set-up-export-application-insights article. What I'm missing is the "Data export (preview)" menu option in my admin.powerplatform.com portal :/.

[image]

Any idea what is the reason of the described situation?

Am I missing some feature? Or should I enable something in my tenant?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see in this link

Analyze model-driven apps and Dataverse telemetry with Application Insights - Power Platform | Micro...

Enablement of Application Insights is limited to customers with a paid/premium Dataverse licenses available for the tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a production / licensed instance?  Also are you admin on that instance? Is the same account in the azure tenant with access to an app insights account?

I believe it should be available in all regions, so if you don't seen in a licensed instanced I would create a support ticket with MS.

Comment: User account I'm using to connect to Power Platform Admin Center uses Power Apps development plan. It has also Global administrator, Dynamics 365 administrator and Power Platform Administrator roles in Azure AD.

Comment: Do you have all of the Azure based prerequistes? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/set-up-export-application-insights#prerequisites  If you do I'd create a ticket with MS to help you at this point.

Comment: All the prerequisites from the above mentioned documentation  are met.